# How NOT to clear previous input in an input field. Button class keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

I need a quick help please. So, I am trying to make this simple `button` keyboard where each of their unique values will be inputted in an `input` box. There is also a simple copy `button`. The only problem that I have is that the current text inside the `input` box is being overwritten by the next text every time I clicked a particular `button`. Is there any simple `vanilla javascript` solution for us to NOT erase the current text and for the new text to be simply written next to the current text? Like writing in a keyboard.

In short, if I will click the buttons `1, 2, 3, A`, it will show as 123A inside the `input` box.

Please forgive my amateurish skills and lack of knowledge. I'm learning this old field of basic computer knowledge at an old age.

**HTML and Vanilla Javascript***

```js
function cyrillicKeys(val) {
  document.getElementById('textfield').value = val;
}

function copyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("textfield");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<input type='button' onclick='cyrillicKeys(this.value);' value='1'>
<input type='button' onclick='cyrillicKeys(this.value);' value='2'>
<input type='button' onclick='cyrillicKeys(this.value);' value='3'>
<input type='button' onclick='cyrillicKeys(this.value);' value='A'>

<input type='text' id='textfield'> <button onclick="copyFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('textfield').value += val;`

Comment: Thank you @CBroe I really appreciate It. That answered it.

Comment: @CBroe brother, would you like to rewrite this comment as an answer? I want to mark it as correct. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value = val` overwrites the input field content on each button click, so *append* to the existing content instead, by using the `+=` operator:

`document.getElementById('textfield').value += val;`